# Mysql - same query different results

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports, odbc, innodb

I am creating a report in Crystal and the report is consistently wrong and we tracked it back to the results being returned from the server.
Environment is MySQL 5.6.19 + MySQL ODBC 5.3.6.
Tables are InnoDB.

The query that Crystal is generating is:

```
SELECT `Encounter`.`Id`, `Transact`.`Client_No`, `Transact`.`Amount`,
       `Transact`.`Process_Date`, `Codelist`.`Type`, `Encounter`.`Co_Res`, 
       `Codelist`.`ProcType`, `Transact`.`Id`, `Client`.`Name`, 
       `Transact`.`Patient_No`, `Transact`.`Encounter_No`, `Transact`.`Quantity`,
       `Encounter`.`Date_Of_Service`, `Encounter`.`Status`, 
       `Insuranceschedule`.`Ins1Order`, `Insuranceschedule`.`Ins2Order`, 
       `Insuranceschedule`.`Ins3Order`, `Insuranceschedule`.`Ins4Order`, 
       `Insuranceschedule`.`Ins5Order`, `Insuranceschedule`.`Ins6Order`,  
       `Ins1`.`Plan_Type`, `Ins2`.`Plan_Type`, `Ins5`.`Plan_Type`, 
       `Encounter`.`No`, `Ins3`.`Plan_Type`, `Ins4`.`Plan_Type`, 
       `Ins6`.`Plan_Type`  
 FROM   {oj (((((((((`Production`.`transact` `Transact` 
   INNER JOIN `Production`.`client` `Client` 
   ON `Transact`.`Client_No`=`Client`.`Client_No`) 
   INNER JOIN `Production`.`codelist` `Codelist` 
   ON `Transact`.`Code`=`Codelist`.`Code`) 
   INNER JOIN `Production`.`Encounter` `Encounter` 
   ON (`Transact`.`Patient_No`=`Encounter`.`Patient_No`) 
     AND (`Transact`.`Encounter_No`=`Encounter`.`No`)) 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN `Production`.`insuranceschedule` `Insuranceschedule` 
   ON `Encounter`.`InsuranceRecord`=`Insuranceschedule`.`Insurance_Id`) 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN `Production`.`Insco` `Ins1` 
   ON `Insuranceschedule`.`Ins1`=`Ins1`.`No`) 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN `Production`.`Insco` `Ins2` 
   ON `Insuranceschedule`.`Ins2`=`Ins2`.`No`) 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN `Production`.`Insco` `Ins3` 
   ON `Insuranceschedule`.`Ins3`=`Ins3`.`No`) 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN `Production`.`Insco` `Ins4` 
   ON `Insuranceschedule`.`Ins4`=`Ins4`.`No`) 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN `Production`.`Insco` `Ins5` 
   ON `Insuranceschedule`.`Ins5`=`Ins5`.`No`) 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN `Production`.`Insco` `Ins6` 
   ON `Insuranceschedule`.`Ins6`=`Ins6`.`No`}  
WHERE  (`Transact`.`Process_Date`>={d '2016-01-01'} 
  AND `Transact`.`Process_Date`<={d '2016-12-31'}) 
  AND `Transact`.`Client_No`=763  ORDER BY `Encounter`.`No`;
```

So far we cannot understand why this result is different almost every time it's run.
First time we might get 57,868 records
Second time.... 30,102
Third time 77,875
and so forth...
At least 1 out of 10 times it does produce the correct result.

We have:
- Dumped the tables and reloaded them.
- Checked collation on the tables.
- Tried a different physical server with a clean import of the data.
- Tried with and without ordering the results
- Looked for anything amiss with EXPLAIN - which is always the same every time it's run.

But this query is consistently inconsistent and we can't spot the problem. We are running this query on the commandline so it can't be Crystal or ODBC - unless the query it's creating is wrong?

Thanks in advance for looking at this!

Comment: your query is crazy. could you show sample of data and expected result you need to get?

Comment: Try to minimize the query and create minimum amount of sample data where the error can still be spotted.

Comment: We actually tried to reduce same size but it just makes the results more consistent. Instead of being wrong 9 out if 10 times it may be wrong 3 out of 10 times. The query was generated by crystal reports... Can you elaborate on why it's crazy? Only part I don't get is the date stuff.

Comment: Have you run the query on database? If not run and check records

Comment: That's where I am running  it. We cut out the report altogether to troubleshoot.

Comment: Stick `LIMIT 20` on the end and run it a few times.  Do you get the same 20 rows?  Try `LIMIT 40000,10`

Comment: I did get the same rows, yes.